# JTA Transactions on asynchronous EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, transactions

I'm thinking to use in our Java EE 6 applications the async features of EJB 3.1. My only concern is how JTA transactions will be managed ? F.e. what happens if I **mix an async call with an EJB sync call** ? will they join the same transaction or async transactions live in a tx context of their own ? 
Thannks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not annotate anything, they will be in the same transaction. An Asynchronous session bean behaves the same as a synchronous one when it comes to transaction propagation between them.

For example, if you have an async method from which you call an sync method of another EJB, then the transaction will propagate as between synchronous EJB methods (i.e by default they will be executed in the transaction).

The only difference is related to the propagation of the *client transaction context*. The specification says:

> Client transaction context does not propagate with an asynchronous
>   method invocation. From the Bean Developer’s view, there is never a
>   transaction context flowing in from the client. This means, for
>   example, that the semantics of the REQUIRED transaction attribute on
>   an asynchronous method are exactly the same as REQUIRES_NEW.

Comment: as you pointed yourself by the quote from specs, it is not always true that "they will be in the same transaction", so the first sentence is confusing.